# Proving a vector field is conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\vec{F}=(P,Q) \in C^1 (\mathbb{R}^2 - (0,0) ) $ such that $Q_x=P_y $ and let $\gamma$ be a closed line surrounding the origin such that $\int_{\gamma} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} =0 $ .
Show that $\vec{F}$ is conservative in $\mathbb{R}^2 -(0,0)$ .

I know I need to show this result by proving that the line integral over every closed line vanishes. So, let $ C $ be such a contour.  I know how to prove this for $C$ that is contained in $\gamma$ and for $C$ that contains $\gamma$. But how can I prove this for the case $\gamma$ and $C $ intersect but one is not contained in the other one?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What does $Q_x = P^y$ mean? None of these letters appear anywhere else in the question...?

Comment: you are right, I am deeply sorry. I put an edit to this

Comment: the origin is inside the region bounded by $\gamma$ . I put an edit to this also

Comment: OK. I understood myself what to do with such lines. I can just circle them with something big enough containing $\gamma$ also. Thanks